# Structs and not clearing / initializing all data

Tags: c++

Ok, so I think I know what I need to do, but I'm not exactly sure how to do it.

I have this struct

```
struct GItemInfo{
string icon = "";
string name = "";
string subname = "";
string rarity = "";
vector<string> ToolTip;
string ToolTipFull;
bool canuse = true;
int depth = 0;
int level = -1;
int leveladjusted = -1;
int slotnum = -1;
bool isslotlocked = true;
int isslothighlighted = 0;
FVector location;
FEntityId id;
float distancetome = 0.0f;
bool istrash = false;
bool ispickuptrash = false;
bool ispickup = false;
bool empty = true;

bool operator<(const GItemInfo& a) const
{
    return distancetome < a.distancetome;
}
};
```

Which I than use

```
vector<GItemInfo> CurrentGearList;
```

To initialize it...problem is... even after I do

```
CurrentGearList.clear();
CurrentGearList.resize(0); // Yes i know some of this is voodoo redundant.
CurrentGearList.resize(20);
```

The values inside of the ID remain, and never actually get re-initialized.
So, the ID struct is simply (int,int)..How can I tell the GItemInfo struct to initialize them as 0,0.

I tried FEntityId id = {0,0}; Doesn't like that.

So I'm sure I need to somehow work within the structs constructor, I'm just not sure how to do it.

Comment: What is the type of FEntityId?

Comment: struct FEntityId
{
 int                                                A;                                                  
 int                                                B;                                                  
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct FEntityID{
    int A;
    int B;

    FEntityID(): A(0), B(0){  
    }
};
```

By creating a default constructor for `FEntityID` every time an object of it is created its `int` values will be initialized with `0`.

If you want to control how your struct objects are initialized for every instance, you should also define your constructors for them.

Comment: Durp, thank you, guess I needed to go one higher...but since we are on the subject.... how do I do the same principle to

vector<string> ToolTip;

Comment: Well... i don't know what is ToolTip :(

Comment: Just a vector of strings, that I want to initialize as ""

Its inside GItemInfo as well

Comment: @Casper7526 by default `vector<string> ToolTip;` is an empty vector, it holds no object strings. You want it to start with an empty string everytime GItemInfo is initialized?

Comment: Well I mean I just want to make sure that it's completely empty everytime, because I don't want the same thing happening with ID to tooltip lol.

Comment: @Casper7526 it's fine as is, quoting `vector`'s default constructor: "Constructs an empty container, with no elements."